# Solidworks VBA Edge Selection Wont Work

Tags: vba, solidworks

I have attached what my macro currently looks like below. So far the macro will make a rectangle with 2 holes in it. It then needs to chamfer the four edge corners. But for some reason when I try to select those corners it wont work. I actually will get different results on different tries.

The code portion in question is the last 7 or so lines. If I run those lines completely separate from the macro I get the results that I am after. Could it just be some syntax thing?

I am new to VBA with respect to Solidworks. I have worked with it in excel. So if you spot any bad habbits other feedback is appreciated.

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swModelDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
    Dim swSketchMgr As SldWorks.SketchManager
    Dim swFeature As SldWorks.Feature
    Dim swFeatureMgr As SldWorks.FeatureManager
    Dim vSkLines As Variant
    Dim boolstatus As Boolean
    Dim longstatus As Long
    Dim circ As SldWorks.SketchSegment
    Dim cx1 As Double
    Dim cx2 As Double
    Dim cy1 As Double
    Dim cy2 As Double
    Dim d1 As Double
    Dim d2 As Double
    Dim b1 As Double
    Dim w1 As Double
    Dim t1 As Double
    Dim in2mmconv As Double
    Dim m2mmconv As Double

    Sub main()
    in2mmconv = 0.0254
    m2mmconv = 1 / 1000
    b1 = 5.5 * in2mmconv
    w1 = 3.5 * in2mmconv
    t1 = 0.75 * in2mmconv
    cy1 = b1 - 1.75 * in2mmconv
    cx1 = w1 / 2
    d1 = 66.779 * m2mmconv + 0.0002 * in2mmconv
    cx2 = cx1
    cy2 = cy1 - 79.3 * m2mmconv
    d2 = 0.5007 * in2mmconv

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

    ' Reset the counts for untitled documents for this macro

    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

    ' Select the Front plane

    Set swModelDocExt = swModel.Extension

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Front Plane", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)

    ' Open a sketch and sketch a rectangle

    Set swSketchMgr = swModel.SketchManager

    swSketchMgr.InsertSketch True

    swModel.ClearSelection2 True

    vSkLines = swSketchMgr.CreateCornerRectangle(0, b1, 0, w1, 0, 0)

    ' Change view orientation and clear all selections

    swModel.ShowNamedView2 "*Trimetric", 8

    swModel.ClearSelection2 True

    ' Select the sketch entities to extrude

    Set swModelDocExt = swModel.Extension

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Line2", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Line1", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Line4", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Line3", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)

    ' Create the extrude feature

    Set swFeatureMgr = swModel.FeatureManager

    Set swFeature = swFeatureMgr.FeatureExtrusion2(True, False, True, 0, 0, t1, 0.381, False, False, False, False, 0.01745329251994, 0.01745329251994, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, 0, 0, False)

    ' Fit the model in the graphics area

    swModel.ViewZoomtofit2

    ' Select the face on the extrude feature

    ' and sketch the entities to pattern

    swModel.ShowNamedView2 "*Front", 1

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("", "FACE", -w1, 0, -t1, False, 0, Nothing, 0)

    Set circ = swSketchMgr.CreateCircle(cx1, cy1, 0, cx1 - d1 / 2, cy1, 0)

    Set circ = swSketchMgr.CreateCircle(cx2, cy2, 0, cx2 - d2 / 2, cy2, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Arc1", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("Arc2", "SKETCHSEGMENT", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)

    swModel.ClearSelection2 True

    Set swFeature = swFeatureMgr.FeatureCut3(True, False, False, swEndCondThroughAll, swEndCondBlind, 0.01, 0.01, False, False, False, False, 0.01745329251994, 0.01745329251994, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, swStartSketchPlane, 0, False)

    swModel.ClearSelection2 True

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("", "EDGE", 0, 0, -t1 / 2, True, 0, Nothing, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("", "EDGE", 0, b1, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("", "EDGE", w1, b1, -t1 / 2, True, 0, Nothing, 0)

    boolstatus = swModelDocExt.SelectByID2("", "EDGE", w1, 0, -t1 / 2, True, 0, Nothing, 0)

    Set swFeature = swFeatureMgr.InsertFeatureChamfer(4, 1, 0.00254, 0.78539816339745, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, these variable names... great missed opportunity for [*proper* Hungarian Notation](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) here: figures in meters could have a `m` prefix, while figures in millimeters could have a `mm` prefix. *Make wrong code look wrong*! ...and use meaningful names, too: wth does `d1` stand for? `cx2`? Also, all these module-scope variables should really be locals, and the conversion factors should be module-scope constants. Get your code working as intended, and then ask on [codereview.se] for feedback on any/all aspects.

Comment: That is part of my problem. I cant get my code to work properly. The last four edge selections will randomly select the wrong lines. But when ran as a completely separate module it works fine. Im not understanding why.

Comment: d1 = diameter 1, cx1 = circle center 1 in x direction

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact that you're declaring your variables in a wider scope than you need to: module-level scope will persist between executions; if the variables aren't `0` when the macro ends, 2nd run will work with the values set by the 1st run. Try moving the variable declarations to procedure scope.

Comment: Assigning `boolstatus` 4 times in a row is discarding 3 of the 4 values, leaving only the last one assigned. Quite a lot is "wrong" in this code, to be honest. If you don't care about what `SelectByID2` returns, then don't bother storing it in a variable.

Comment: But to actually select an edge dont you need to store the variable. If you dont I get a compile error.

Comment: Also moving variables to the procedure scope had the same effect as where they originally were.

Comment: You only need the variable if you have the parentheses, for the syntax to be valid. Drop the variable *and* the parentheses; the *function* call will look like any other *procedure* call. As for procedure-scoped variables, they *belong* at procedure scope. I'm afraid I can't help you with debugging. Use breakpoints (F9), step-through (F8), step-over (Shift+F8), the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) and the *locals* toolwindow to step through your code and see what's going wrong where.

Comment: Okay I will make some changes tonight and see what i can figure out. Because when i got rid of the storing of the variable and parenthesis the same thing happened. and I have stepped through my code and nothing looks wrong to me personally. But this is the first thing i have done in solidworks. Ive only been able to go off of official solidworks examples. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148636/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-slinkmon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem recently. After some google search, I found that the selectbyID2 method may behave in certain circumstances. One of them is that there is an edge that is over your required edge. And there are so many of them. So, what did I do in my code? I planned to rotate the model so that the required object to be selected is in normal view. In my case, this procedure solved my issues completely. Try it.
To rotate the model, use the showNamedView2 method before using selectbyID2.